# Angular 2 keydowns on radio input triggers (click) event

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a radio button group to which I have bound a click event handler. I'm doing accessibility testing now for keyboard users and have found that every arrow key press is triggering the (click) handler and being logged as a MouseEvent. I cannot fathom why this is the case and its stuffing up my functionality because it means users can basically only ever select the first option.

Can anyone shed light on this?

```
<div class="flex-container neg-margins hidden-sm hidden-xs">
     <div class="flex-child col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"

         *ngFor="let option of question.subCats">          
        <!--<label [for]="option.id">{{option.label}}</label>-->
        <input class="choice-input" 
               type="radio" 
               [name]="question.id" 
               [id]="option.id" 
               (keyup.space)="onKey($event, question)"
               (click)="onKey($event)"
               [attr.aria-labelledby]="option.id"
        >
        <div class="c-label-holder" 
             [ngStyle]="{'border-top': highlightColor(option.bdrColor)}" 
             [ngClass]="{'selectedCat': option?.isSelected}"
        >

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of a click event, did you try change event?

Comment: I hadn't, but in trying it just then it has the same effect as click, it only allows the user to select the first option. I've figured a way around it to make my solution work the way I want, I'm more just interested as to why Angular or the Browser is converting key presses into MouseEvents.